# How to plot additional raster with spplot?

Tags: r, plot, gis

I want to plot SpatialPolygonsDataFrame as a semi-transparent main object (with legend on the right), but I want to plot yet additional raster (hillshade) as a background - just to make nicer map. I would need something like:

```
spplot(polygons, sp.layout = list(list("raster", myRaster)))
```

but looking at `?spplot`, it doesn't seem to be possible to specify the raster in `sp.layout`. I can't specify the raster as the main object, because the main object are the `polygons` dataFrame, whose value scale I want to plot in the legend on the right side.

#### How is it possible to plot an additional raster in spplot?

Comment: Cross posted: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/122994/4630

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. There's probably a neater way to achieve it without plotting the polygon object twice, though...

```
library(sp)
library(rasterVis)
r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
r[r > 8] <- NA
pol <- rasterToPolygons(r, function(x) x > 6)
spplot(pol) + levelplot(r) + spplot(pol)
```

[image]

Or alternatively:

```
library(latticeExtra)
spplot(pol) + spplot(r) + spplot(pol)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

As per the comment by @OscarPerpiñán, a better way to do this is:

```
spplot(pol) + as.layer(spplot(r), under = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks jbaums, I will try it. You can *sum* the plots?? What does it do?

Comment: @TMS - it's a `+` method provided by `latticeExtra` (I think). See `?latticeExtra::layer`.

Comment: With `as.layer` you can simplify the call: `spplot(pol) + as.layer(levelplot(r), under = TRUE)` or `spplot(pol) + as.layer(spplot(r), under = TRUE)`.

Comment: @Oscar - fantastic, thanks. Not sure how I missed `under` in the docs.

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán - thanks, your solution is much faster, but it is not equivalent to the original jbaums' solution. In my case the raster levelplot (or spplot) image will be resampled to lower resolution, because the spatial extent of the levelplot raster is bigger than the polygon raster. Do you guys know how to keep the high image resolution of the final raster plot even in the Oscar's solution?

Comment: @TMS I cannot understand why do you get different results with both solutions. Please, post a reproducible example.

Comment: @TMS I'm not sure about this either... e.g. after `r2 <- crop(r, extent(r, 5, 10, 5, 10)); pol <- rasterToPolygons(r2, function(x) x > 6)`, both `spplot(pol) + as.layer(spplot(r), under = TRUE)` and `spplot(pol) + spplot(r) + spplot(pol)` yield the same result (i.e., a plot cropped to the extent of `pol`).

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán, jbaums: because these rasters have very low resolution. This resampling issue will start to show up when the raster is 1000x1000 pixels. I cannot post my data as an example because it is huge.